# Copying contents of a cell to a different worksheet in same workbook.

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I need to copy contents of a cell in one worksheet to another worksheet. Currently i have this code. What is wrong with it? It gives me error when i run it. The Number of worksheets are not constant. I need to copy the contents of the cell C4 to the last worksheet of the workbook.

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

         Dim Store As Integer
         Dim WS_Count As Integer
         WS_Count = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count

            Store = ActiveWorkbooks.Sheets(5).Range("C4").Value
            ActiveWorkbooks.Sheets(WS_Count).Range("C4").Value = Store

End Sub
```

Comment: it will give error if your sheet number is less than 5. Also what is WS_count?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that line. Edited code

Comment: Ok, first you should use `ActiveWorkbook` and not `ActiveWorkbooks`. Then as i've said in my post, better if you specify the `Sheet name` of the source. If your sheets are less than 5, `Sheets(5)` will throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
Sub WorksheetLoop()

Dim Store As Integer

Store = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet_name").Range("C4").Value 'Better to specify the name of the sheet
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Range("C4").Value = Store
'This writes the value of Store in C4 of the last sheet
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Can i call the sheets out in numbers instead of it's name? For example Sheets(1) is first sheet, Sheets(n) is n'th sheet. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, that is possible but be sure that you will not assign a number greater than the total number of sheets. How do you determine the source data? i mean the sheet numnber?

Comment: I have 20 worksheets in the workbook The program needs to copy cell C4 in all the worksheets, and paste it in a new worksheet. I have already completed it. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: np. which help i provided helped you? :D hehe just curious.

Comment: The code you gave and the info about being able to use numbers to address sheets, haha :)